# adb windows 8 64bit

Tags: android, adb, windows-8

К сожалению, купил и установил на компьютер Windows 8 Pro 64 и теперь возникла проблема с подключением девайса. Повествование касательно самсунг, но думаю с другими вендорами будет аналогично. Установил все нужные тулзы для разработки, установил Samsung kies - подключил по usb девайс - он его не видит. Драйвера через кайс ставил - результат аналогичный. Смутило, что обычно win 7, например, ставил драйвера устройства и потом все хорошо, девайс видно из Eclipse. Теперь же такого не было.

Слышал, что это из-за того, что стоит настройка отказа установки устройства с неподписанным драйвером, но пока не нашел где эту шнягу выключить.

Может, ну может, кто-нибудь, ну пожалуйста :) сталкивался с подобной проблемой и знает ее решение?

Второй вопрос тоже наметился: avd не запускается(видимо из-за C:/Users/русские буквы) - напомните как решить и это за одно. Помню как-то перемещал avd и указывал путь.

Comment: JDK/JRE ставили под x86 и x64 оба? К драйверам отношения не имеет, но к Eclipse отношение точно имеет.

Comment: Да, ставил под х64 JDK. Тут кстати есть забавная вещь - Android SDK остался от семерки(х86) и прекрасно заработал тут:) Eclipse под х64, classic, последняя версия.

Comment: А x86 JDK не ставил?

Comment: нет, из-за этого может быть?

Comment: @DroidAlex Считаю да, из-за этого может быть, потому что 32-х битные приложения будут вызывать 32-х битную Java, а 64-х битное свою

Comment: Проверю ради интереса, но решение уже нашел:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все решается иначе, спасибо хабраюзеру serso за ссылку - [PdaNet](http://junefabrics.com/android/)

Comment: Да я тоже этим способом пользовался)

Answer (score 3):

У меня тоже Windows 8 Pro x64, Eclipse 3.7.2 с установленным AVD,SDK, драйвер (samsung_usb_driver_for_mobile_phones) для моего Samsung Galaxy W, и установлена галочка "Отладка USB", всё работает без проблем.

Кайс вообще не использую.)

> Слышал, что это из-за того, что стоит настройка отказа установки устройства с неподписанным драйвером, но пока не нашел где эту шнягу выключить.

Впервые слышу.)

> Второй вопрос тоже наметился: avd не запускается(видимо из-за C:/Users/русские буквы) - напомните как решить и это за одно. Помню как-то перемещал avd и указывал путь.

[Пишем своё первое приложение на Android](http://habrahabr.ru/post/109944/) - в самом низу описано. такая же была проблема.

Comment: Это странно. Галочка эта тоже стоит, девайс Galaxy Ace. Сдается мне, что все дело в новом Kies, который как-то выдавал "Данное устройство не поддерживается блаблабла". Кайс не используете, а драйвера с ним обычно идут) хотя наверное отдельно скачали.

Comment: Да верно, драйвера я качал отдельно. Погугли samsung_usb_driver_for_mobile_phones

Comment: Это понятно, странно то что на семерке девайс при подключении ставил свои драйвера, а здесь - нет. Вот что смущает.

Answer (score 0):

Запрет установки не подписанных драйверов в Windows отключается в консоли.
Cmd 
Bcdedit.exe -set testsigning on
 Эта команда переводит систему в тестовый режим для разработчиков. В этом режиме отключается проверка цифровой подписи